# How to confirm app exit when appbar back button is pressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to confirm exiting the app when the back button on the appbar is pressed.

```
 appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back_ios,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('Save and Exit?'),
                    content: Text('are you sure you want to save and exit?'),
                    actions: [
                      FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
                        child: Text('No'),
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
                        child: Text('Yes'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              );
              // Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
```

I tried this but didn't work.
I have found some answers on how to do it when the system back button is pressed using `WillPopScope` but none of them work in my case.

Help me out

Comment: `Navigator.pop` should be called twice, one for closing the dialog and the other to close the app. just add another  `Navigator.pop` in yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it with Navigator.canPop(context) i guess. It will return true or false.
in onPressed you can check it, if it's true you can do Navigator.pop(context) otherwise call showDialog.

there is link of doc
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/canPop.html