# Notify user for terminating app in flutter

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I am trying to send local notification to user when it clears application from background in Flutter. I tried to do this using AppLifecycleState with WidgetsBindingObserver. I tried to call send notification in Applifecyclestate.detach but code is not execute when app was killed.

```
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        print('\ncalled detached paused\n');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        print('\ncalled detached resumed\n');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        sendNotification('App should not terminate');
        print('\ncalled detached method\n');
        break;
    }
  }
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673353 look at this maybe will help you

Comment: No use. I want to execute some code just before app is killed by user.

Comment: You can't. When the user terminates the app it just dies